# php pdo_informix on rhel6 - Optional feature not implemented

Tags: php, linux, pdo, informix

I've configured pdo_informix:

```
[root@cc-allplus nginx]# php -i |egrep "pdo|PDO"
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, sqlite2, odbc, pgsql, informix, dblib
pdo_dblib
PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled
pdo_informix
pdo_informix support => enabled
PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
Revision =>  $Id: pdo_pgsql.c 300351 2010-06-10 12:11:19Z iliaa $
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

and trying out to create connection :

```
try{

    $dbh = new PDO ("informix:host=some.example.ru; service=50000; database=test; server=test_net; protocol=onsoctcp;DB_LOCALE=en_US.57372; CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.57372;", "dcs_test", "********");

    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Failed to execute your db connection: '. $e->getMessage().'</br>'; exit;
    }
```

And the response is :

```
Failed to execute your db connection: SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLSetConnectAttr: -11097 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Optional feature not implemented
```

Googling not helped with resolving this issue.. any suggesions are welcome

Comment: Is there an Informix implementation (in your php version)?

Comment: Php was rebuilt --with-pdo --with-pdo-informix

Comment: Have you checked the output of phpinfo() for informix?

Comment: Yes, it is presrnted, and i made php to show informix in the list of loaded pdo libs in console..

Comment: What's the result if you omit DB_LOCALE and CLIENT_LOCALE?

Comment: If i cut them from connection string, than another error occurs, that ask to set db locale

Comment: And if you just omit CLIENT_LOCALE? Can't find it here anyway: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php

Comment: Same error, about optional feature not implemented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87474/discussion-between-altenrion-and-m02ph3u5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved.
For those who might stuck with the same troubles with informix or others pdo's libraries I would like to share.

My trouble was in choosing the latest version of PDO_INFORMIX soursec. As I searched and discovered, **php 5.3** need **informix not later than 1.2.6** version.

I discovered that information from an article **in Hungarian language**, and it was the only post about such incompatibility between php and `PDO_INFORMIX` in whole www.

Not any string of such info at IBM site, nor at pdo PECL sources site.. God, that take me a few days, but I did it!

After I found right version I had to recompile the php, cause it have put 1.3.0 version of informix pdo in cache and didn't want to work with older one.

Hope that would help!